# Data Flow Diagram (DFD) Question about how to link caching system with the main API

Tags: database, security, dataflow-diagram, dfd

I’m trying to build a DFD diagram but I was confused about caching system which is used to make the data run faster.

Is the diagram below in correct order or should I make another link from caching system to the database?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The diagram uses the [Yourdon/DeMarco](https://online.visual-paradigm.com/knowledge/software-design/dfd-using-yourdon-and-demarco) notation. There is only one active process `The Core Application API`.  The `Caching System` and the `MySQL Database` are both data stores.  According to Yourdon/DeMarco, a data store is:

> a repository of data, a time-delayed data flow, a file

All a data store can do, is to store and retrieve data at the request of a process. But it is not itself process data and interact directly with other data stores. So there shall not be a direct link between the cache and the database.

**If your `Core application API` manages the cache**, your diagram is fine.  I'd nevertheless rename `Caching system` (which suggest an active process) to `Cache` (which better reflects a repository).

If not, and **if the cache system manages itself in direct interaction with the database**, you would need to transform it into a separate process `Cache system` which you'd insert in the flows between your core application and the database.  This new process should then have flows with the database, with the application process and a new `Cache` data store.

*Btw, I'd recommend to remove `API` from the name of your process: the API is just the interface to the application and not the application itself.*